# How would I start with making a game for ti-nspire cx ii using lua?

Tags: lua, game-development, ti-nspire

I've wanted to start to make simple games using lua for the ti-nspire cx ii and I cant really find any good places to start. I am pretty good at coding in geniral and have some experince using JavaScrip and C#. Any help or redirections would be greatly appreciated.

Ive just started to play around with lua wia onecompiler but I have no clue how to get graphics on the screen.

Comment: Dont have find the References? Every Coder should know. - The Lua API and Examples is documented for example here: https://education.ti.com/de/guidebook/details/en/59108CCE54484B76AF68879C217D47B2/ti-nspire_scripting-api-guide

Comment: Hint: The Lua 5.1 used by TI is sandboxed - See '1.6 Unimplemented Libraries and Functions' (TI-Nspire Lua Scripting API Reference Guide.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find this tutorial very helpful https://compasstech.com.au/TNS_Authoring/Scripting/lua_tutorials.html. Of course you can also look at the official [documentation](https://education.ti.com/de/guidebook/details/en/59108CCE54484B76AF68879C217D47B2/ti-nspire_scripting-api-guide), but I think that without any prior experience, just reading the docs can be a bit daunting. You should know though, that Lua by default has no way to handle graphics, so for whatever testing you may want to do, you will either have to do it on your calculator, or on the computer app. You may also want to install an on-calc IDE. I personally like [Jens Lua IDE](https://tiplanet.org/forum/archives_voir.php?id=88209)

PS: I was shocked to find that ndless-apps.org is no longer operational : (

It's such a shame, because it's largely because of it that I became so interested in scripting and low level programming for embedded systems...